# Control cell value from another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, cell, calc

Having this image:

[image]

Is there some way of having something like a "control cell"? E.g.: if B1 (the control cell) has some text, B3 displays "HELLO"; if B1 is empty, B3 displays "NONE". I can solve it with an IF function in B2, but if I write something in this B2, I will lose the IF formula, so I need to control it from another cell.

If that isn't clear enough, here's another example:

[image]

I want to show "?" in all cells under Exam 3 *only* if D1 has text. Otherwise, they will be blank. I want to put grades in these cells, but if I remove the grade, I want to recover the "?" value, so I think I need to control this value from another cell in order to not lose the formula.

Comment: Displaying a question mark won't be possible. What will be possible however is conditional formatting a cell to be a color for example. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, JvdV. I am already using conditional formats, but is not what I need. I need to set the value, not the style. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you will need to resort to VBA. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having two tables, one for INPUT and one for viewing - in essence, a summary table. Then your formula would be as simple as an IF statement and a COUNTA.

For the Formula in C2 of the summary table, you could try something like:

`=IF(COUNTA('Input Table'!$B2:C2)<1,"?",'Input Table'!C2)`

This formula assumes you have the INPUT data in the same columns as the screenshot you provided in a sheet named "Input Table"

In Cell D2, you would do the same, but extend the references:

`=IF(COUNTA('Input Table'!$B2:D2)<1,"?",'Input Table'!D2)`

Ideally though,  as another contributor said though, the best way is VBA if you are able.

Comment: I finally ended up using macros. Thanks yo you all.

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to solve it. VBA is definitely the easiest way.